# IDX Broker Responsive Results Page

Tags: css, responsive-design, idx, idxbroker

I am having a hard time making the results boxes on this page responsive:

http://search.epicmountainhomes.com/i/deer-valley-real-estate

Does anyone know how to edit it using IDX broker or custom CSS?

Thank you very much!

Comment: [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) looks like a good solution.

Comment: Flexbox actually looks like a way better solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out:

```
/*Set Mobile Responsiveness One*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.IDX-resultsCell {
    padding-bottom: 22px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5eeed !important;
    clear: left!important;
    width: 100%!important;
}
}

/*Set Mobile Responsiveness Two*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.IDX-grid .IDX-resultsPhotoImg {
    height: 155%!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    clear: left!important;
    left: 0!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    top: auto!important;
    z-index: 0!important;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none;
    min-height: none;
    min-width: none;
}
}
```